# Difficult integral by parallel programming

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Can I do this in parallel programming??

I want to integrate this function where all parameters are constant variable is z and summation over n but i am not be able to do it can anyone help to figure out this. it would be a great pleasure,

```
aMie[n_, x_] := (m psi[n, m x] psidev[n, x] - psi[n, x] psidev[n, m x])/
        (m psi[n, m x] xidev[n, x] - xi[n, x] psidev[n, m x]);
bMie[n_, x_] := (psi[n, m x] psidev[n, x] - m psi[n, x] psidev[n, m ,x])/
        (psi[n, m x] xidev[n, x] - m xi[n, x] psidev[n, m x]);

pn[θ_, n_] := (LegendreP[n - 1, Cos[θ]] - LegendreP[n + 1, Cos[θ]])/(1 - (Cos[θ])^2);
tn[θ_, n_] := -Cos[θ]*pn[θ, n] + (2*n + 1)*LegendreP[n, Cos[θ]];
dn[θ_, n_] := (pn[θ, n] + tn[θ, n])/(2*n + 1); 

Gn[n_] := NIntegrate[NIntegrate[Sin[θ]*Sqrt[Cos[θ]]* Exp[-γ^2*(Sin[θ])^2]*Exp[I*δ*Cos[θ]]*
    dn[θ, n], {θ, 0, ϕmax}],{δ,0,Infinity};
```

Comment: Do you want an analytical solution?

Comment: Taking a quick inspection in the code one can see that the integration will do not proceed unless you define the following variables m, gama, phimax. Also the evaluation in the Table[] command needs the definition of alpha, k and function A[phimax].

Answer (score 2):

Everything is actually ok with your code and the full integration cannot proceed mainly because the function call psidev[n, m ,x]) instead psidev[n, m x]). However the analytic integration seems to be very difficult to accomplish with these complicated expressions and here I give a numerical approach to the problem. In this manner, in order to evaluate the NIntegrate[] kernel one needs to adopt a convenient integration strategy/rule to circumvent the function subtleties. In fact this integration takes place in a complex domain and an additional care must to be taken in the calculation. Here, I do not worry about this, but it may have important consequences if there exists poles in this domain. 
The functions are highly oscillatory and possibly a tunning procedure in the integration method can speed up the elapsed computation time. The calculation presented below took several hours in my computer. 
Here I've changed the Table[] command by a For[] loop to better see what is happening during the entire evaluation.

```
    m = 1.33/1.5;
    \[Phi]max = 78*\[Pi]/100;
    \[Gamma] = Sqrt[0.99];
    A = 0.98;
    k = 1.38*10^7;
    \[Alpha] = 13.829;


    psi[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
     x SphericalBesselJ[n, x](*Riccarti \.06Bessel \.06Functions*)

    xi[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := x SphericalHankelH2[n, x]
    psidev[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := Derivative[0, 1][psi][n, x];
    xidev[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := Derivative[0, 1][xi][n, x];


    aMie[n_?NumericQ, 
       x_?NumericQ] := (m psi[n, m x] psidev[n, x] - 
         psi[n, x] psidev[n, m x])/(m psi[n, m x] xidev[n, x] - 
         xi[n, x] psidev[n, m x]);
    bMie[n_?NumericQ, 
       x_?NumericQ] := (psi[n, m x] psidev[n, x] - 
         m psi[n, x] psidev[n, m x])/(psi[n, m x] xidev[n, x] - 
         m xi[n, x] psidev[n, m x]);

    pn[\[Theta]_?NumericQ, 
       n_?NumericQ] := (LegendreP[n - 1, Cos[\[Theta]]] - 
         LegendreP[n + 1, Cos[\[Theta]]])/(1 - (Cos[\[Theta]])^2);
    tn[\[Theta]_?NumericQ, 
       n_?NumericQ] := -Cos[\[Theta]]*pn[\[Theta], n] + (2*n + 1)*
        LegendreP[n, Cos[\[Theta]]];
    dn[\[Theta]_?NumericQ, 
       n_?NumericQ] := (pn[\[Theta], n] + tn[\[Theta], n])/(2*n + 1);

    Gn[n_?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ] := 
      NIntegrate[
        Sin[\[Theta]]*Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]]*
         Exp[-\[Gamma]^2*(Sin[\[Theta]])^2]*Exp[I*\[Delta]*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
         dn[\[Theta], n], {\[Theta], 0, \[Phi]max}, 
        Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT", 
          "SingularityDepth" -> Infinity, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
        MaxRecursion -> 200, PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10] // 
       FullSimplify;

    GNp[n_?NumericQ, \[Delta]_?NumericQ] := Derivative[0, 1][Gn][n, \[Delta]];

    (*Qe=Table[{z,Re[Sum[((4*\[Gamma]^2)/A*(2*n+1)*(aMie[n,\[Alpha]]+bMie[\
    n,\[Alpha]])*Gn[n,k*z]*Conjugate[GNp[n,k*z]]),{n,1,10}]]},{z,10^-5,10^\
    -4,10^-6}]*)


Result = List[];

For[i = 0, i <= 90, i++,
 z = N[10^-5 + i*10^-6];
 func = Re[
   Sum[((4*\[Gamma]^2)/
       A*(2*n + 1)*(aMie[n, \[Alpha]] + bMie[n, \[Alpha]])*Gn[n, k*z]*
      Conjugate[GNp[n, k*z]]), {n, 1, 10}]];
 AppendTo[Result, {z, func}];
 Print[z, "     ", func]
 ]

ListLinePlot[Result, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 0.5,
  PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, Background -> White, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.0045]], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.0035]], 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, Opacity[1]], 
 RotateLabel -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["z", FontSize -> 20], 
   StyleForm["Sum", FontSize -> 20]}, Frame -> True]
```

Choosing a z interval starting at 10^-5 and ending at 10^-4, we have the table output

> {{0.00001, -0.0144983}, {0.000011, -0.0119027}, {0.000012,  -0.00979571}, {0.000013, -0.00814835}, {0.000014, -0.00692311},  {0.000015, -0.00604408}, {0.000016, -0.00540571}, {0.000017,  -0.00490035}, {0.000018, -0.00444597}, {0.000019, -0.0040016},  {0.00002, -0.003566}, {0.000021, -0.0031629}, {0.000022,  -0.00282066}, {0.000023, -0.00255521}, {0.000024, -0.00236225},  {0.000025, -0.0022199}, {0.000026, -0.00209895}, {0.000027,  -0.00197487}, {0.000028, -0.00183635}, {0.000029, -0.00168711},  {0.00003, -0.0015412}, {0.000031, -0.00141466}, {0.000032,  -0.00131755}, {0.000033, -0.00124969}, {0.000034, -0.00120152},  {0.000035, -0.00115903}, {0.000036, -0.00111008}, {0.000037,  -0.00104928}, {0.000038, -0.000979359}, {0.000039, -0.000908869},  {0.00004, -0.000847562}, {0.000041, -0.000801744}, {0.000042,  -0.000771639}, {0.000043, -0.000751732}, {0.000044, -0.000733649},  {0.000045, -0.000710058}, {0.000046, -0.000677772}, {0.000047,  -0.000638726}, {0.000048, -0.000598594}, {0.000049, -0.000563853},  {0.00005, -0.000538736}, {0.000051, -0.000523447}, {0.000052,  -0.000514335}, {0.000053, -0.00050579}, {0.000054, -0.000492889},  {0.000055, -0.000473527}, {0.000056, -0.000449134}, {0.000057,  -0.000423741}, {0.000058, -0.000401943}, {0.000059, -0.000386746},  {0.00006, -0.000378291}, {0.000061, -0.000373955}, {0.000062,  -0.000369706}, {0.000063, -0.000362005}, {0.000064, -0.000349369},  {0.000065, -0.0003329}, {0.000066, -0.000315611}, {0.000067,  -0.000300922}, {0.000068, -0.000291065}, {0.000069, -0.000286126},  {0.00007, -0.000284117}, {0.000071, -0.000281992}, {0.000072,  -0.000277088}, {0.000073, -0.000268312}, {0.000074, -0.000256544},  {0.000075, -0.000244122}, {0.000076, -0.000233689}, {0.000077,  -0.000226959}, {0.000078, -0.000223977}, {0.000079, -0.000223175},  {0.00008, -0.00022217}, {0.000081, -0.000218888}, {0.000082,  -0.000212494}, {0.000083, -0.000203714}, {0.000084, -0.000194416},  {0.000085, -0.000186701}, {0.000086, -0.000181922}, {0.000087,  -0.000180093}, {0.000088, -0.000179944}, {0.000089, -0.000179555},  {0.00009, -0.000177268}, {0.000091, -0.000172431}, {0.000092,  -0.000165653}, {0.000093, -0.000158465}, {0.000094, -0.000152576},  {0.000095, -0.000149076}, {0.000096, -0.000147959}, {0.000097,  -0.000148169}, {0.000098, -0.000148128}, {0.000099, -0.00014648},  {0.0001, -0.000142707}}

This list gives us the following plot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your great effort. Can I use a loop for n summation because I have to sum it over n=1 to infinity.

Comment: How did you got this plot??

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari I've edited the answer above and inserted the ListLinePlot part.

Comment: is there any way to reduce timing in summing over 1 to infinity??Here we add it for 1 to 10 but extending it to 20 is also taking long timing.

Comment: Probably yes, the evaluation time can be reduced by adjusting the integration strategy. The LocalAdaptive strategy takes a long time in the process since secctionates the interval in a certain number of partitions. Maybe another approach can work better and faster than this one. You can take a look at the documentation. http://www.johnboccio.com/MathematicaTutorials/06_AdvancedNumericalIntegrationInMathematica.pdf. I'll try some more adjustments and post the results too soon as possible.

Comment: okay. Thank you

Comment: The main responsible for the large evaluation time of the code when one sets the summation limit to infinity  seems to be the slow convergence rate of Bessel partial waves infinite sum. In order to accelerate the convergence rate one can implement methods in NSum[] command like WynnEpsilon.  In this thesis http://calhoun.nps.edu/bitstream/handle/10945/26069/miescatteringser00john.pdf?sequence=1 there is a long discussion about the application of a Levin transform to accelerate the convergence rate of this Mie scattering problem.

Comment: Also, changing the NIntegration method to Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, 
  Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
  "SymbolicProcessing" -> 
   0}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5, helps to decrease the evaluation time.

Comment: I tried this but in my desktop this is not making much difference.

Comment: Can I do this code in parallel programming in mathematica to reduce time??

Comment: You can try the `ParallelDo` instead of `For` but you need to share the previously defined function before this to make it available for parallel kernels. So, set the `SharedVariables` and try, but remember that parallelization will consume the memory a lot.

Comment: If I want to do double inumeric integration w.r.t. n from 0 to infinity how can I do for Gn.